# How can i get my API data to display vertically instead of horizontally in Intellij?

Tags: java, json, spring, endpoint

I am trying to format the data received from my API so that each value populates on its own individual line. Currently the data returns horizontal within my Safari and Chrome browser. I have tried to add  " +/n" to my API and that did not work. I have attempted to search for a solution on Stack Overflow as well as on Google, neither resource provides a solution for my task. Below is the details of the IDE version I am working on:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2 EAP (Community Edition)
Build #IC-232.7754.73, built on June 15, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.7+7-b985.2 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.4.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 10
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    ide.experimental.ui=true


Kotlin: 232-1.8.21-release-380-IJ7754.73
```

Comment: I think your image is of the Chrome debug console. It's showing a rendered view of your JSON, not the raw text. There's another tab in the debug console to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this is my second time ever dealing with Stack Overflow to ask a question and it seems more difficult than expected to share screenshots and details like I want to.

Comment: Here is how my data displays within any browser right now:

[{"email":"Terence@aol.com + /n","password":"test123"}]

Comment: This is my current code within my controller:

 @GetMapping()
    public List<User> getUsers(){
    return List.of(
        new User(
                1L,
                 "Terence@aol.com" ,
            "test123"
        )
        );

        }

Comment: If you are looking for a line break, that's `\n`, not `/n`.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that error, I have made that modification and instead of the data going to the next line, "\n" has been added within the same string.

Comment: There is an extension for Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa

Comment: @Mar-Z I knew it had to be an easy solution thank you for the guidance, that worked!